# How can I redistribute skill points in Elder Scrolls Online?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I wanted to go a different skill path and so I went to a city looking for something like a class trainer but I couldn't find one. Now I wonder whether or not I can actually redistribute my skill points and and if yes: where and at what cost?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are no class trainers and only the Divines will be able to help your poor soul - seriously.

You'll have to find a **Shrine to Stendarr** (or **Shrine to Stuhn** if you're in the Ebonheart Pact) to reset your skill points and apply them once again.

Keep in mind that this "service" requires a donation of *some* gold.

You're able to find such a shrine in each capital, based on your alliance. It's always located in the second mainland (post newbie island) zone:

- **Aldmeri Dominion:** *Eldenroot* in *Grahtwood*
- **Daggerfall Covenant:** *Wayrest* in *Stormhaven*
- **Ebonheart Pact:** *Mournhold* in *Deshaan*

If you'd like to redistribute your attribute points as well, you'll have to look for different shrines based on your alliance - they can be found in the same cities:

- **Aldmeri Dominion:** *Shrine to Auriel*
- **Daggerfall Covenant:** *Shrine to Akatosh*
- **Ebonheart Pact:** *Shrine to Kyne*

Comment: Thanks, very clear answer ( I was looking for this answer for a while ). Do you by any means know how much the cost is or vaguely how it is calculated?

Comment: From what I've heard, it's 100 gold per (skill) point reset. Not sure about attributes though.

Comment: Wow, that's a steep curve :p unless you can pick the skill points you want to reset?

Comment: It is 100g per skill point, and you reset all of them. Not sure you pay for skill points you have not allocated. Also note that any skill you spec out of will keep their ranks, but skills you spec into will of course start at rank 1 (or the rank you might've had previously if you've already specced away from them and now want to get back). Switching skills is thus a bit like old-style WoW, in that you probably want to visit a lower-level zone and train up your skills a bit before venturing back into the zones you're currently playing in.

Comment: Just to answer to your first sentence in that answer: Nope, even The Divine can't help his soul as he is the Soulless One. :) Nice answer!