# Does resetting skills get more and more expensive?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

Can you reset skills as many times as you want, or will the price per point increase based on how many times I used the reset option?

Comment: If my answer was help full to you, you can consider marking it as a accepted answer. If my answer was not what you were looking for, you can leave a comment on my answer with some information about what was missing.

Answer (score 1):

The price for a reset is determined by the amount of skills points (or attribute points) that need to be reset.

I believe the current price for this is 50 gold per point.

So as you level up, you will have more skill points to reset.
But the amount of times that you respec has no direct influence on the price.

> Related questions: [Gold cost to respec](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/266562/gold-cost-to-respec-skills) & [How and where to
>   respec](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/163421/how-can-i-redistribute-skill-points-in-elder-scrolls-online)